# Elm - Displaying Text Character By Character (with pauses)

Tags: signals, elm

I'm an Elm newbie, and as an experiment, I am trying to display a string one character at a time at a certain rate. This much I've already accomplished. However, I'd like to introduce a brief pause in the output whenever the program hits an end of sentence character (period, question mark, interrobang, whatever). However, I can't figure out how to make this pause happen.

This is the working code I have (minus the pauses of course):

```
import Time (..)
import Signal (..)
import Text (..)
import String

stringOut : String -> Float -> Signal String
stringOut str rate = let 
    t = round <~ (foldp (+) 0 <| (flip (/) rate) <~ fps 60)
  in flip String.left str <~ t

main = asText <~ stringOut "This is a string. Yeah?" (20*millisecond)
```

My initial thoughts are that I should use the delay function in the Time module, but I'm not sure where to fit it in without ending up with a `Signal Signal Int`. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Signal of Signal problems

Problems with `Signal (Signal x)` usually come from using or defining functions that return `Signal`s. It's best to avoid those in general.

## Problem and Solution

Now, if I understand your desired system correctly, you have a static piece of text, a counter that ticks a certain rate, on every tick a new character of the text should be displayed, but at certain characters signifying end-of-sentence there should be a pause.

The time ticks are the basic input to your program. If you keep count of more than just how far along you are in the text, you can introduce your pause. You need to keep track of whether and how far you are in the pause. Every time you hit the end of a sentence you set the pause, every tick either eats away at the pause to continues the offset into the text.

### Code

This may be a bit overkill but I formalised the inputs and state of your program and wrote it in a generally scalable style:

```
import Time
import Time (Time)
import Signal
import Signal (Signal, (<~))
import Text (asText)
import String
import List
import Graphics.Element (Element)

type alias Input = ()
type alias State = { text : String, offset : Int, delay : Int }

initialState : State
initialState = { text = "This is a string. Yeah?", offset = 0, delay = 0 }
stdRate : Time
stdRate = 50 * Time.millisecond
stdDelay : Int
stdDelay = 5
endOfSentence : List String
endOfSentence = [".", "?", "!"]

input : Signal Input
input = always () <~ Time.every stdRate

state : Signal State
state = Signal.foldp (always step) initialState input

step : State -> State
step state =
  let
    newChar = String.slice state.offset (state.offset+1) state.text
  in
    if| state.delay > 0 -> { state | delay <- state.delay-1 }
      | List.member newChar endOfSentence ->
        { state | offset <- state.offset + 1, delay <- stdDelay }
      | otherwise -> { state | offset <- state.offset + 1 }

view : State -> String
view { text, offset } = String.left offset text

main : Signal Element
main = asText << view <~ state
```